# search contacts and get the contact number from phone contacts in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am working with an app, in this I have to search contacts when the button click and select one of the contact from phone contacts. Finally I want to set it to `edittext`.I can able to search the contacts from phone contacts but I am unable to get contact from phone contacts.

activity:

```
searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);

}
});
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode==RESULT_OK){
Uri contactData = data.getData();
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow
(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

//contactName.setText(name);
ephoneNumber.setText(number);
//contactEmail.setText(email);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First set Intent for StartActivityForResult Like this

```
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
```

then deal with result what intent carry from native contact application

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
            String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

            // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
            // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
            // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
            // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
            // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);

            // Do something with the phone number...
        }
    }
}
```

see another reference links

[Link 1](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)
[Link 2](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker--mobile-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Bharat,

You need permission like -

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Then, Calling the Contact Picker

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

Then,

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

switch (reqCode) {
case (PICK_CONTACT) :
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Uri contactData = data.getData();
    Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
      String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
      // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact name.
    }
  }
  break;
  }
 }
```

OR, In other way You can  use

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID);
    int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
    int photoIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.PHOTO_ID);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String idContact = cursor.getString(contactIdIdx);
        String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
        String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
        //...
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());  
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Above solution is simple and working for contact number fetching.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(mActivity,
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
managedCursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
String conTactnumber=managedCursor.getString(number);               
String contactname=managedCursor.getString(name);

set permission   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" >
</uses-permission>
```